# update property values of one object by matching key values of another?

Tags: javascript

**Object 1:**

```
var obj1 = {
  location : 'lol',
  radius : '22'
}
```

**Object 2:**

```
var obj2 = {
  location : 'omg',
  spice : 'gravey',
  radius : '8'
}
```

I need a recursive function to update the values of properties that match in `obj1` from `obj2`:

```
obj1 = update(obj1,obj2);

//console.log(obj1);
//{
//  location : 'omg',
//  radius : '8'
//}
```

*Native JavaScript only please.*

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
function update(o1, o2){
    var temp = {};
    for(var key in o1){
        if (o1.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            temp[key] = o1[key];
            if (o2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                temp[key] = o2[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple.  Just loop through the 1st object, and use the values (if they exist) from the 2nd object.

```
function update(obj1, obj2){
    var ret = {};
    for(var prop in obj1){
        ret[prop] = obj2[prop] || obj1[prop];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Yeah, I just hacked this up quickly.  I didn't really add any validation :)

Comment: This will set values from Obj2 that aren't in Obj1

Comment: @meouw: What do you mean?  No it won't.  `for(var prop in obj1){`